# Optimization of non-smooth, non-convex, locally Lipschitz functions of type exp(-abs(x))

Tags: optimization, nonconvex

What would be the numerical method of choice to find minima in a non-smooth, non-convex, locally Lipschitz function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The function $f$ is mostly smooth but contains three-dimensional cusps of the following form:
$$
g: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
g(\boldsymbol{x})= -\exp(-{\lVert \boldsymbol x \rVert}_2)
$$
with $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ being the Euclidean Norm.

Comment: I just tried to minimize the function $g$ that you present using [SQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming) in Python and it converged after 8 iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the right article myself:

[Lewis, A.S. & Overton, M.L. Math. Program. (2013) 141: 135. doi:10.1007/s10107-012-0514-2](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10107-012-0514-2)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the right approach: non-smooth Newton methods.